# react web app responds slowly after gradients are added

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a project I'm working on and for some reason after I added some gradients the page responds very slowly and even trying to resize the page especially horizontally will lag excessively. Taking the gradients out will fix things so it has to be something with the gradients. What could be causing this issue? here is the site hosted on render
https://reactbankapp.onrender.com/

hero section with issues gradient code is at the bottom

```
import styles from '../style';
import { discount, robot } from '../assets';
import GetStarted from './GetStarted';

const Hero = () => (
  <section id='home' className={`flex md:flex-row flex-col ${styles.paddingY}`}>
    <div className={`flex-1 ${styles.flexStart} flex-col xl:px-0 sm:px-16 px-6`}>
      <div className='flex flex-row items-center py-[6px] px-4 bg-discount-gradient 
        rounded-[10px] mb-2'>
        <img src={discount} alt='discount' className='w-[32px] h-[32px]' />
        <p className={`${styles.paragraph} ml-2`}>
          <span className='text-white'>20%</span> Discount For{' '}
          <span className='text-white'>1 Month</span> Account
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className='flex flex-row justify-between items-center w-full'>
        <h1 className='flex-1 font-poppins font-semibold ss:text-[72px]
          text-[52px] text-white ss:leading-[100-px] leading-[75px]' >
          The Next <br className='sm:block hidden' />{' '}
          <span className='text-gradient'>Generation</span>{' '}
        </h1>
        <div className='ss:flex hidden md:mr-4 mr-0'>
          <GetStarted />
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 className='font-poppins font-semibold ss:text-[68px]
          text-[52px] text-white ss:leading-[100-px] leading-[75px] w-full'>
          Payment Method.
      </h1>
      <p className={`${styles.paragraph} max-w-[470px] mt-5`}>
        Our team of experts uses a methodology to identify the credit cards most
        likely to fit your needs. We examine annual percentage rates, annual
        fees.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div className={`flex-1 flex ${styles.flexCenter} md:my-0 my-10 relative`}>
      <img
        src={robot}
        alt='billing'
        className='w-[100%] h-[100%] relative z-[5]'
      />

      <div className='absolute z-[0] w-[40%] h-[35%] top-0 pink__gradient' />
      <div className='absolute z-[1] w-[80%] h-[80%] rounded-full bottom-40 white__gradient' />
      <div className='absolute z-[0] w-[50%] h-[50%] right-20 bottom-20 blue__gradient' />
    </div>

    <div className={`ss:hidden ${styles.flexCenter}`}>
      <GetStarted />
    </div>
  </section>
);

export default Hero;
```

style.js

```
const styles = {
    boxWidth: "xl:max-w-[1280px] w-full",
  
    heading2: "font-poppins font-semibold xs:text-[48px] text-[40px] text-white xs:leading-[76.8px] leading-[66.8px] w-full",
    paragraph: "font-poppins font-normal text-dimWhite text-[18px] leading-[30.8px]",
  
    flexCenter: "flex justify-center items-center",
    flexStart: "flex justify-center items-start",
  
    paddingX: "sm:px-16 px-6",
    paddingY: "sm:py-16 py-6",
    padding: "sm:px-16 px-6 sm:py-12 py-4",
  
    marginX: "sm:mx-16 mx-6",
    marginY: "sm:my-16 my-6",
  };
  
  export const layout = {
    section: `flex md:flex-row flex-col ${styles.paddingY}`,
    sectionReverse: `flex md:flex-row flex-col-reverse ${styles.paddingY}`,
  
    sectionImgReverse: `flex-1 flex ${styles.flexCenter} md:mr-10 mr-0 md:mt-0 mt-10 relative`,
    sectionImg: `flex-1 flex ${styles.flexCenter} md:ml-10 ml-0 md:mt-0 mt-10 relative`,
  
    sectionInfo: `flex-1 ${styles.flexStart} flex-col`,
  };
  
  export default styles;
```

index.css for gradients

```
.blue__gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(188, 165, 255, 0) 0%, #214d76 100%);
  filter: blur(123px);
}

.pink__gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f4c4f3 0%, #fc67fa 100%);
  filter: blur(900px);
}

.white__gradient {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  filter: blur(750px);
}
```

Comment: Those blur operations are probably expensive. Together with the opacity of the `.white__gradient`. Not sure if it is just the linear-gradients.

Comment: got it its definitely the blur. so my only options to fix this is to use node to host this site via server?

Comment: what do you mean? CSS is interpreted by the browser renderer which happens clientside. No server solution can solve this. Your best bet is to remove the blur (for instance only on smaller screens or mobile devices)